NextUI Datepicker, how to create a Datevalue?
I am trying to use the new DatePicker in NextUI library but I get the error
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'DateValue | null | undefined'.
Type 'Date' is missing the following properties from type 'ZonedDateTime': #private, calendar, era, year, and 16 more.
I cant find any information on how to create a "DateValue"
Component:
<DatePicker
  label="date"
  color="secondary"
  className="w-48"
  aria-label="Date"
  variant={"underlined"}
  defaultValue={new Date()}
/>

Please help, Thank you!

I solved it, but if anyone has the same problem in the future use
use any time of parse in the @internationalized/date provided by nextui
import { parseDate, parseAbsolute... } from "@internationalized/date";

<DatePicker
   label="date"
   color="secondary"
   className="w-48"
   aria-label="Date"
   variant={"underlined"}
   defaultValue={parseDate("2024-04-24")}
/>


Thank you, bro.
I faced with the same issue and you saved for me several hours...

this worked but how you parse 2024-11-29T04:44:39Z i have tried other methods but no luck

In that case you should use the parseAbsolute instead
